# How to securely allow a PHP script to save files?

Tags: permissions, apache2, php

I have a PHP script that is supposed to save images to `/var/www/backend/images/` folder.
The script is in `/var/www/html/save_image.php`

The owner and the group of all the folders and files in `/var/www/` is `ubuntu`.

For testing, this is my simple script that won't work:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

And I get the following message:

> Warning: fopen(newfile.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied
> in /var/www/html/save_image.php on line 2 Unable to open file!

How can I allow this script only to save files?

Comment: Silly question, but do you mean the PHP script is going to save files to `/var/www/backend/images`? Otherwise, if you want to save to a location outside of the `/var/www` location, you'll need to make some changes to Apache's AppArmor configuration so the web server has permission to write to a different location.

Comment: yes in `/var/`. Sorry about that, I will add the post. Not outside the `/var/`

Comment: Next question would be: is the `ubuntu` account configured as the owner of the Apache process? Generally — but not always — Apache is run with the `www-data` account. This would mean that `/var/www` and any subdirectories would need to be owned or writable by that account.

Comment: I think that I own all the files and folders in `/var/` with `ubuntu` user because I think I did `chown` once. In FileZilla I see that `ubuntu` is both owner and group on all items in `/var/` and not `www-data` Or I didn't do `chown` but because I'm using AWS EC2 then it configures `ubuntu` and not `www-data`

Comment: Ah, EC2. That explains the account name. Then you’ll want to do this: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`. Unless you specifically changed your Apache config to use the default user account, then Apache is using `www-data` 

Comment: Thank you. After I do that, it should work?

Comment: So long as the code is correct, yes. Apache will have write permissions.

Comment: Maybe I can do `usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu`? to add `ubuntu` to `www-data` instead? Will that work either?

Comment: That would also work, but I would advise against adding a public web server to a group primarily used by admins. Either add `ubuntu` to `www-data` or create a new group for both accounts to be in 

Comment: Thank you! It works now!! You can write an answer and I'll choose it. Btw, how can I undo the 2 following commands that I did: `sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu` and then I did  `sudo chmod g+w /var/www/html -R`

Comment: Removing a user from a group is done with `deluser` ⇢ `sudo deluser www-data ubuntu`. Permissions can be set with `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117210/discussion-between-pileup-and-matigo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache service is typically run from the `www-data` account so, unless you intentionally changed it, you will need to do this:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed the user was `ubuntu` because I am using AWS